# Error when uploading Hyperledger's orderer.exemple.com to the docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I'm having trouble uploading the Hyperledger Fabric 2.2.1 network, after running `docker-compose -f docker-compose.yaml up -d`, to upload images to the docker. The `orderer.exemple.com` never goes up, it just looks like exited (1) n seconds ago.

[Here's the output for your reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5okZg.png)

Error:

```
UTC [orderer.common.server] initializeServerConfig -> FATA 0f8 Failed to load ServerRootCAs file 'open /etc/hyperledger/fabric/ordererca: no such file or directory' (/etc/hyperledger/fabric/ordererca)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check if you have setup ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ROOTCAS path correctly for the orderers

Comment: My ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ROOTCAS look like this           - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ROOTCAS=[/etc/hyperledger/msp/orderer/tls/ca.crt, ordererca]

Comment: Thank you very much for this hit @GPC , this solved my problem